# How to aggravate values based on DateTime if Date not start from 00:00:00 in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

Hello I have problem with agg (sum) values based on DateTime. Problem is , "Day" should start on 5:00 and end on 4:00.
DateTime : Values
2023-07-01 05:00:00 : 10 -- start day
2023-07-01 06:00:00 : 10
...
2023-07-02 04:00:00 : 10 -- end day
2023-07-02 05:00:00 : 10
2023-07-02 06:00:00 : 10

and sum for should be agg table with 2023-07-01 = 240 and 2023-07-02 = 20

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data
data = {
    'DateTime': [
        '2023-07-01 05:00:00',
        '2023-07-01 06:00:00',
        '2023-07-02 04:00:00',
        '2023-07-02 05:00:00',
        '2023-07-02 06:00:00'
    ],
    'Values': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
}

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert DateTime column to datetime type
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

# Adjust DateTime values by subtracting 5 hours
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'] - pd.DateOffset(hours=5)

# Create CustomDate column
df['CustomDate'] = df['DateTime'].dt.date

# Group by CustomDate and calculate sum of values
agg
```

Adjust the DateTime values by subtracting 5 hours from each timestamp.

Comment: thank you so much  
At the moment I solved problem with 
df['Test'] = df["DateTime"] - datetime.timedelta(hours=5)

But thank you :)